# How to get 1:1 scale in Keynote, Pages or Numbers?

Tags: preview, screen, keynote

I was an early user of Mac last century; I remember Jobs telling about how the Plus had the only screen with square pixels and how important it was for developers a consistent info on pixel size so that they could give to the user an exact scale. That if an image was being shown 100% scale in the screen, one centimeter in the ruler should be a real centimeter.

I think that this consistency was a key to win the field of graphic design.

So, I got a new 21.5 iMac some months ago and yesterday I discovered that the images I was sketching at 100% size were not the size I was seen in the screen. I enabled the ruler and measured it. Whoops, I need to set zoom at 150% to get a correct size, and even then it is a bit, sort if one hundredth part, inaccurate.

To my amazement, Preview does the 100% size right when showing pdfs, so the info on pixel size is available to developers... My guess is that I am missing some setting, is it?

EDIT: LibreOffice also does the right scale, so it is something with the adjusts of AppleWorks applications. Er... iWorks.

Comment: What is your scaling set to in System preferences -> Display?

Comment: Default. If I set it to 768 lines then 20 cm at 100% measure 21cm, which is good enough, but I miss all the ability of seeing small typesizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select '**Actual Size**' (<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>) under the **View > Zoom** menu, then the page should display at ... actual size.

With this setting, an A4 page on the screen is the same size as an A4 piece of paper that I hold in front of the screen. This works for Retina displays and non-Retina displays.

Back in the old days, Mac screens had 72 pixels to the inch. So it was easy for 1 point on the page to equal 1 pixel on the screen. This ratio is what became 100% zoom.

Of course, screen pixel density has increased massively since then. Many pre-Retina displays were around 109 dpi. Retina screens are twice that, but scale everything up by 2, giving the same perceived resolution.

As a result, 72 pixels are *less than an inch* on such a display. So you have to use a higher zoom level to get Actual Size.

109 dpi divided by 72 dpi gives you 151%, which is the zoom factor you get when you select 'Actual Size' on a display with that pixel density.

[image]

**In other words, the zoom % set for Actual Size will depend on the pixel density of your display.**

Preview has a Preference to define 100% as either 1 point = 1 pixel, or 'size on screen equals size on printout', which presumably sets 100% to the Actual Size.

Comment: Oh, it works! I feel still a bit not intuitive, this 151, but it solves the issue. Now I only wished a way to go 4K without such small menu bars.

Comment: @arivero Ask another question about that: but the whole point of a 4K *Retina* display is that it 'doubles up' the pixels, so the image is NOT tiny, but the image is detailed.

Comment: An extra remark: Pages produces the 151%. Keynote seems to ignore it, because even if it allows to set centimeters in the ruler, it seems to consider that the basic unit is pixels. I missed the "Actual Size" because I was doing most of my testing with Keynote.