# What is that right scaling if you want "wysiwyg" in Pages?

Tags: display, pages, resolution

I have for a long time been annoyed by the difference in appreciated size of a document viewed on screen in Pages and the actual printout, but haven't done anything about it until yesterday, when it struck me that I could just hold up a paper on my computer screen and compare.

Lo and behold, the zoom factor that made the document on screen's width correspond to the physical paper was approximately 178 % (to achieve that zoom level you have to use `Adapt to width` (my translation) and then drag the window until you "reach" 178 %).

This value was very surprising and **I am interested in why such an uneven (yeah, yeah, 178 is even, but values such as 100, 200, 75 or ⅔ are even in this context) value corresponds to the actual physical size?**

AFAIK Apple/MacOS used to calculate with 72 dpi (and Windows 96 dpi) as the monitor resolution (and 144 dpi when they introduced "retina" monitors).

I am using a Macbook Air 13" with 1440 × 900 apparent resolution (2880 × 1800 physical resolution).

Comment: Use `Command 0` to get Actual Size. The Zoom value depends on your display's pixel density. See my answer here. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396853/how-to-get-11-scale-in-keynote-pages-or-numbers/396879#396879

Comment: No, my question is why 178 % is 1:1. How can that be hard to understand? I even marked that with bold in my question.

Comment: Because your display has a pixel density of 256 ppi, which when scaled by 2 for Retina is 128 ppi, which is 178% of 72 pixels to the inch.

Comment: @benwiggy Thank you for your answer. Too bad it is marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I've added a sentence to the linked original answer to explicitly state that the Actual Size zoom value is dependent on the pixel density of your display.